# How to send attachment file?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

In php mail() function, how can I send attachments? I didn't find parameter to do this. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here's an article with an example: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Comment: [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) makes it rather easy to add attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a multi-part flag you can set somewhere to enable the connection to stay connected until the persons upload is finished.

try this:
http://snipplr.com/view/2686/send-multipart-encoded-mail-with-attachments/